# How to output LogCat to Console?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way to make LogCat's output to appear in Console view in Eclipse?

LogCat view is much less convenient that Console, because it's hard to see long messages in it (they are trimmed by column border) and there are no clickable highlighting in exception stack traces to quickly navigate to source of error.

Just to make clear - I'd like to have clickable stacktraces, like the ones in normal Eclipse console so I can quickly navigate to the source of error.

Comment: have you considered logging them to a file from command prompt(terminal) using :

adb logcat > filename.txt ???

Comment: If I can feed that file into Eclipse Console that would solve the problem, I think. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Depending on your platform you need a utility to read the file and put it on the clipboard.  That clipboard can be pasted in the java stack trace view inside Console

Comment: Thorbjørn, could you please explain in more detail? What and where do I have to paste? Generally I can't paste anything into Console view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requires an extra step, but you can copy and paste into the Console Stack Trace View, and you then get the clickable links. Just select any or all lines from Logcat, copy, and paste them in the Console (select Java Stack Trace in the Console Display button first).

Comment: How can this help me with my problem?

Comment: @Shooshpanchick: sorry, I originally misread the question - I've edited my answer now.

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue. I tried ddms instead of logcat, it doesn't put up in Eclipse but it solves my problem. It displays the logs in different colors so that i can view and differentiate them easily.... Thanks....

Comment: I will +1 this if you can add an example of how to use ddms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. You could just move the Logcat to another place.
e.g. In the bottom of Eclipse.
Just drag&drop it by grabing its tab.

Comment: I know how to move views in Eclipse. What I want is clickable stacktraces.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the LOGBACK plugin ;-)

http://logback.qos.ch/consolePlugin.html

GOOD LUCK!!

Comment: How to stream LogCat to this plugin's console?

Answer (score -1):

Instead Logcat, try ddms. It puts the log messages differentiated based on their type and you'll have much more control over log message filtering in ddms.

This binary is located in the same place where logcat is located. So no worries.... instead of typing out logcat, type ddms in console.

Comment: Is there any difference between log in DDMS and LogCat view in Eclipse? Anyway, I want an Eclipse solution so I can have clickable stacktraces.